# select where id in csv string - how to do something if row is missing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a csv string and need to select rows having corresponding id.
And need to do something specific if a row doesn't exist.

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12';
$st = $db->query("select *
                  from arts
                  where id in (" . $str . ")
                  order by field (id, " . $str . ")");
$arr = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    // if ($el is missing) {echo 'the row is missing';}  // how to do this?
    else { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option here, assuming you are stuck with the input CSV string, is to use `FIND_IN_SET`, something along these lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, FIND_IN_SET(id, :list) AS result FROM arts";
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':list', $str); 
$stmt->execute();

$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($arr as $el){
    if ($el["result"] <= 0) {
        echo "the row is missing for id " . $el["id"];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `$el["result"]` ? There is no such a column

Comment: @qadenza I define an _alias_ called `result` in my query.  It is the output of applying `FIND_IN_SET` to the current row's `id` value against your CSV list.  So, in fact `$el["result"]` should be defined.

Comment: Won't this return every arts record, as opposed to just those that may be in the set?

Comment: @NigelRen If we leave the OP's current restriction in the `WHERE` clause, then only records which match the CSV string would be returned.  But, the OP's code seems to want to flag records which did _not_ match.

Comment: And what if the records don't exist on the database for the ones they want to match?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than look at the records found, this code first keys the retrieved records on the id and then looks through the ID's you are looking for and if this record isn't found (using `isset()`) then process the not found part...

```
$arr = array_column($arr, null, "id");
$ids = explode(",", $str);
foreach($ids as $el){
    if(!isset($arr[$el]))   {
        echo 'the row is missing';
    }  else{
        echo 'the row is there';
    }
}
```